# How to recursively enrich json object with custom field using python jsons

Tags: python, python-jsons

I'm using [jsons](https://jsons.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library and would like to add a custom serializer that for a given type adds a certain field.

Naive example:

```
def adjust(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, MyFoo):
        json = jsons.dump(obj)
        json['foo'] = "bar"
        return json
jsons.set_serializer(lambda obj, **_: adjust(obj), MyFoo)
json = jsons.dump(data, ensure_ascii=True)
```

This doesn't work because it goes into infinite recursion. I tried playing with forks but couldn't make it work.

What is important, `MyFoo` might appear inside other `MyFoo`s and so the serializer must work on all levels.

Comment: Out of more than 50 existing questions tagged [tag:python-jsons], this was the **only one** that was actually about the `jsons` library, which is what the tag is presumably intended for. I retagged all the others.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it. The trick was to use `jsons.default_object_serializer`

```
def adjust(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, MyFoo):
        json = jsons.default_object_serializer(obj)
        json['foo'] = "bar"
        return json
jsons.set_serializer(lambda obj, **_: adjust(obj), MyFoo)
json = jsons.dump(data, ensure_ascii=True)
```